# Derivative of a finite sum

Tags: derivatives, summation

I'm trying to find the derivative with respect to x of the following:

$V = \sum_{i = 0}^{P} x_i y_i$

Does simply putting the derivative inside the sum work? That is,

$V_x = \sum_{i = 0}^{P} y_i$

Or... changing indexes maybe? I don't know, and from searching online I can't find much on this (just on power series).

Comment: I don't think $x$ should have an index: $x$ is the variable with respect to which you are differentiating. Otherwise, yes: this is one of the main reasons that series representations of functions are so useful in calculus.

Comment: I'm positive x has an index, that's why I was confused.

Comment: Is there an expression for $x$ in terms of the $x_i$?

Comment: In general, $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d}{dx} f_i(x)$ when $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: In that case, which $x$ are you differentiating with respect to? All the other terms would be constants and differentiate to zero... Is $x$ a vector with $x_i$ as components?

Comment: I don't know which x, probably all of them, I think it might be as @benguin said.